# Angular component conflict since same component added on a page multiple times

Tags: angular

I have a reusable multi select component .On one page(in another component) there is case where I have added this component (multi select reusable compoenent) multiple times.

But angular treating it as one component and both component behave in sync (If i select checkbox from component one then from second component it get selected)

I tried giving name to component but it didnt work.

I also tried placing component in separate form still its not working.

Sample Code :

```
<label>Selection 1:</label>
<custom-multi-select [suggestions]="suggestions"></custom-multi-select>
<label>Selection 2:</label>
<custom-multi-select [suggestions]="suggestions"></custom-multi-select>
```

from first multi-select if i check any checkbox same checkbox from second multi-select get selected

Comment: please post your relevant code

Comment: Could You provide some additional code via Stackblitz? As I know, Angular should accept without a problem multiple components at once.

Comment: *But angular treating it as one component and both component behave in sync* Its not Angular, its you that wrote it this way - either you use some static fields, or common instance of data model.

Comment: right  # Antoniossss .. Actually i created copy of model but it was shallow copy ...now i created deep copy and its working fine :) ... thanks... you changed direction of my thinking

Comment: How did you fix this issue..I do have the same problem